# FCM Quickstart app has crashed with IllegalAccessError

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement push notifications on Androind using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). So I've imported Google's quickstart project from GitHab (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging/). And I run app on my Android. But the app has crashed. The detail environment and error message is below. Please look into this issue.

## Environment

Android Studio 2.3.3

## Project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'  // Added MODULE_VERSION = "9.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        google()
    }
}
```

## App level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
check.dependsOn 'assembleDebugAndroidTest'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-beta2'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'

    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0-beta2'

    // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'  // Added in accordance with https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup but conflicted
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'


    // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'  // Added in accordance with https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup but conflicted
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'

    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'

    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Added in accordance with https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
```

## Logcat

```
08-04 16:01:16.749 6218-6218/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-04 16:01:16.749 6218-6218/? I/art: Reinit property: dalvik.vm.checkjni= false
08-04 16:01:16.805 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm-2/lib/arm64
08-04 16:01:16.846 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
                                                                               java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6257)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5775)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5693)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6577)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm-2/base.apk)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)?
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)?
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)?
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)?
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)?
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)?
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)?
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)?
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)?
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6257)?
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5775)?
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5693)?
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)?
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637)?
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)?
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)?
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6577)?
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)?
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)?
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)?
08-04 16:01:16.857 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9080
08-04 16:01:16.857 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
08-04 16:01:16.874 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
08-04 16:01:16.884 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustActivityImpl
08-04 16:01:16.912 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-04 16:01:16.997 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
08-04 16:01:17.002 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
08-04 16:01:17.068 6218-6258/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-04 16:01:17.079 6218-6258/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm W/linker: /vendor/lib64/libhwuibp.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xe3a
08-04 16:01:17.160 6218-6247/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm-2/base.apk): com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzEd(Unknown Source)
08-04 16:01:22.011 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
08-04 16:01:23.141 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm I/hwaps: JNI_OnLoad
08-04 16:01:23.289 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm, PID: 6218
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm-2/base.apk)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:92)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6577)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
08-04 16:01:23.306 6218-6218/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6218 SIG: 9
```

Comment: why don't you create an issue in that github repository?

Comment: Try changing firebase-core  and messaging library version to 11.0.2

Comment: First of all try updating your buildToolsVersion to 26.0.1. Also, all of your FCM dependencies shoud be of the same and preferably, newest, version. Try setting both of them to 11.0.4.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll try later. :)